# AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Tags: object, set, attributeerror

I was scrapy with python2.7

then this happened:

[image: Errorcode]

[image: Spider(I will not mention Domain.)]

Plase help me, Thank you

Comment: `I was scrapy` looks off: _Using [scrapy](https://scrapy.org) ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rYqC.png))_?

Comment: Please don't just use `this` and a link: include in your post the pivotal information - as text, preferably. Even if, in the case of the error message you get, that means essentially repeating the title.